# How come my AVD Xamarin Live Player always shows "Paired with Visual Studio"?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-virtual-device, mobile-development

Everything is fine when I am using a real Android device to run Xamarin Live Player.

However, when I start Xamarin Live Player in an AVD. It just start with paired status and I cannot do anything to scan the qrcode or enter the pair code.

Anyone can help?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio automatically installs Live Player and pairs with the Android emulator. No pairing code is required and Visual Studio will auto-start/run the Live Player so you do not need to open it manually.

1. Start the Emulator
2. In Visual Studio:

   1. Set your startup project to the `Xamarin.Android` application project
   2. Select the running emulator from the available Virtual Devices
   3. Open a XAML page and click the `Live Run` button

Comment: Since I am running the VS in a VM. Therefore, I cannot start the AVD in the same system with VS (x86 AVD cannot run on a VM). The soulution for me is to run an AVD in the VM host and develop with VS in VM and then pair them up by Live Player. I just wonder why the app shows me it has paired with VS when I have just start it up and seems it is not really paired with anything... Still thanks with your solution!

Comment: @mannok If Visual Studio "sees" your AVD via the Android Debug Bridge (`avd`) and you can start a normal debugging session on it, then Live Player will work. If Visual Studio can not see the running emulator, then you will need to forward the port, Xamarin has examples of this when running VS in a VM guest when using a macOS host on their site, there are also multiple web posts concerning this via Windows guests and hosts, etc... (using SSH/Putty or `mkfifo` or ... to perform the port forwarding)